# Why can I assign characters to string objects but not to vectors of string objects?

Tags: c++, string, vector, character, variable-assignment

C++ Primer says that character and string literals may be converted to `string`s.

I tried assigning a character to a `string` as:

```
std::string s;
s = 's';
```

And it gave me no error.

But, when I tried to assign characters to a `vector` of `string`s object as:

```
std::vector<std::string> svec;
svec = {'a', 'b'};
```

It gave me an error. Why?

Comment: Because `std::vector` cannot implicitly convert char arguments to strings.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> C++ Primer says that character and string literals may be converted to `string`s.

C-style string literals can convert to `std::string` implicitly, but `char`s can't.  That's different from assignment.

`s = 's';` works because `std::string` has an overloaded [`operator=`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%3D) taking `char`.

> 4. Replaces the contents with character `ch` as if by `assign(std::addressof(ch), 1)`

`svec = {'a', 'b'};` doesn't work because `std::vector` only has overloaded [`operator=`s](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator%3D) taking `std::vector` or `std::initializer_list`, both of them can't be constructed from braced-init-list `{'a', 'b'}`. You might think the overload taking `std::initializer_list<std::string>` could be used for this case, but `char` can't be converted to `std::string` implicitly (`std::string` doesn't have such [converting constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) taking a `char`), then `std::initializer_list<std::string>` failed to be constructed from `{'a', 'b'}`.

As the workaround, you can change the code to

```
svec = {"a", "b"};
```

`"a"` is of type `const char[2]` and decays `const char*`, which could be converted to `std::string` implicitly (via the [`std::string`'s converting constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) taking `const char*`), then `std::initializer_list<std::string>` gets constructed from `{"a", "b"}` and passed to `std::vector::operator=`. Of course `svec = {std::string("a"), std::string("b")};` (or `svec = {"a"s, "b"s};`) works too, `std::initializer_list<std::string>` will be constructed directly without such implicit conversion to `std::string`.

Answer (score 16):

The assignment of a character literal in the first expression works because the `std::string` class [has an overload for the assignment operator](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator=/) that takes `char`.

The character literal arguments in the second expression cannot be implicitly converted to strings, like string literals can (i.e. `svec = {"a", "b"}`), because `std::string` [has a constructor for `const char*` but not for `char`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/):

The expression:

```
svec = {"a", "b"};
```

uses the constructor

```
string (const char* s);
```

The expression:

```
svec = {'a', 'b'};
```

can't work because no such constructor exists that takes a single character argument.

What it does have is a constructor that takes an `initializer_list` (as you can see in the previous link):

```
string (initializer_list<char> il);
```

[Available since C++11](https://wandbox.org/permlink/wZFgMOOQ0FmdLh2S).

So to initialize `std::string` with character literals you need to use curly brackets (i.e. [braced initializer list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization)):

```
std::vector<std::string> svec;
svec = {{'a'}, {'b'}};
```

This will, as you know, initialize 2 strings in the first 2 positions of the vector one contains `"a"` and the other `"b"`.

For a single string in the first position of the vector you can use:

```
svec = {{'a','b'}};
```

Answer (score 7):

The key to understanding this is initializer lists.

First, note that this does not work:

```
  std::string s('a');
```

but this does:

```
  std::string s{'a'};
```

The reason is that the first one would require a ctor that takes a single `char`, but `std::string` does not have such a constructor. The second, on the other hand, creates an `initializer_list<char>`, for which `std::string` does have a ctor.

The exact same reasoning applies to

```
  std::vector<std::string>> vs{ 'a', 'b' };
```

versus

```
  std::vector<std::string>> vs{ {'a'}, {'b'} };
```

The first wants to use a non-existent `std::string` ctor taking a `char`, and the second uses initializer lists.

As for the original code, the reason that

```
  std::string s;
  s = 'a';
```

works is that while `std::string` lacks a ctor taking a `char`, it does have an assignment operator which takes a `char`.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the following example:

```
#include <initializer_list>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> svec;
    
    // Non-ambigously deduced to std::initializer_list<char>.
    auto a = {'a', 'b'};
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<std::initializer_list<char>, decltype(a)>);
    
    // (A)
    // error: no match for 'operator=' (... std::vector<std::string> and 'std::initializer_list<char>')
    //svec = a;  
    //svec = std::initializer_list<char>{'a', 'b'};
    
    // error:
    // error: unable to deduce 'std::initializer_list<auto>' from '{{'a', 'b'}}'
    //auto b = {{'a', 'b'}};
    
    // (B)
    // OK. 
    // After all the following copy assingnments, svec.size() is 1 (a single "ab" element).
    svec = {{'a', 'b'}};
    svec = std::initializer_list<std::string>{{'a', 'b'}};
    svec = std::initializer_list<std::string>{std::initializer_list<char>{'a', 'b'}};
    svec = std::initializer_list<std::string>{"ab"};
}
```

The error message at **(A)** is self-explanatory: there exist no copy assignment operator for `std::vector<std::string>` to assign a `std::initializer_list<char>` argument to it. The only near-viable overload of [`std::vector<T,Allocator>::operator=`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator%3D) requires an argument of type `std::initializer_list<T>`:

> ```
> vector& operator=( std::initializer_list<T> ilist );
> ```
>
> Replaces the contents with those identified by initializer list `ilist`.

but `T` in this example is `std::string`, thus this overload is not viable.

In **(B)**, on the other hand, we use the nested braced init syntax `{{'a', 'b'}}` such that the *inner* braced init list represents a `std::initializer_list<char>`, which may make use of [the following `std::string` constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string):

> ```
> basic_string( std::initializer_list<CharT> ilist,
> ```

```
                const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

to create a *single* `std::string` temporary which is in turned part of the outer braced init list, making use of `std::vector` copy assignment operator mention above:

> ```
> vector& operator=( std::initializer_list<T> ilist )
> ```

The result of the different variations of **(B)** is the same: copy assigning to the `svec` vector a vector of a *single `std::string` element*.

Finally, note that if you were to copy assign to `svec` using a braced init list of `"`-separated *strings*, the result is copy assigning a vector of *two elements*:

```
svec = {"a", "b"};  // svec.size() is now 2
```

as we are no directly creating a `std::initializer_list<std::string>` of *two elements*, as compared to above where a `std::initializer_list<char>` of several *characters* result in a *single string*. I.e., a single `std::string` object is also *a container* of (zero or) several `char` elements.